# Why python2 is working on xampp server and python3 not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, python-2.7, xampp

I tried to use python on xampp server but it is not working It gives some server error message
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3yQ0.png)

> ```
> Erreur du serveur!
> Le serveur a été victime d'une erreur interne et n'a pas été capable de faire aboutir votre requête.
>
> Message d'erreur:
> End of script output before headers: python.py
>
> Si vous pensez qu'il s'agit d'une erreur du serveur, veuillez contacter le webmestre.
>
> Error 500
> localhost
> Apache/2.4.53 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1o PHP/8.1.6 mod_perl/2.0.12 Perl/v5.34.1
> ```

even when I type in my python file
`#!/usr/bin/python`
But when I type
`#!/usr/bin/python2`
It works.
my code in python is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print("content-type: text/html\n\n" )

print("hello world")
```

I follow all the instructiond of adding .py to *addHundler* and the two lines at the end but It still not working
I'm working on kali linux

Comment: XAMPP contains Apache, MariaDB, PHP, and Perl. The Python version has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Hello @Soufianneamimi and welcome to StackOverflow! Please include your code and the full error message so we can assist you better.

Answer (score 0):

At some point in the last year (or more), Kali Linux removed the `/usr/bin/python` binary/link, instead you have to specify `/usr/bin/python2` or `/usr/bin/python3` to run the version you want.

On a fresh install of Kali Linux, you can see this very clearly (I'm using their rolling Kali docker image to demonstrate).

```
docker run -it kalilinux/kali-rolling

┌──(root㉿0b2aea58ed90)-[/]
└─# which python python2 python3
# no tools exist in a completely new image

┌──(root㉿0b2aea58ed90)-[/]
└─# apt update && apt install -y python2 python3

┌──(root㉿0b2aea58ed90)-[/]
└─# which python2 python3 python
/usr/bin/python2
/usr/bin/python3

# nothing for /usr/bin/python
```

If you want to use Python3, use either of these at the top of the script you're talking about:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

**If you really want** `/usr/bin/python` to point to `/usr/bin/python3`, you can install `python-is-python3` which will set up the symlink for you. This isn't really recommended unless you can't avoid this need for whatever reason.

Install with...

```
apt install python-is-python3
```

And it should work like so:

```
┌──(root㉿0b2aea58ed90)-[/]
└─# apt install python-is-python3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python-is-python3
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
Need to get 2852 B of archives.
After this operation, 13.3 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main arm64 python-is-python3 all 3.9.2-2 [2852 B]
Fetched 2852 B in 0s (12.7 kB/s)
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Selecting previously unselected package python-is-python3.
(Reading database ... 8373 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python-is-python3_3.9.2-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-is-python3 (3.9.2-2) ...
Setting up python-is-python3 (3.9.2-2) ...

┌──(root㉿0b2aea58ed90)-[/]
└─# which python
/usr/bin/python

┌──(root㉿0b2aea58ed90)-[/]
└─# python -V
Python 3.10.5

┌──(root㉿0b2aea58ed90)-[/]
└─# ls -l /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 7 Oct 11  2021 /usr/bin/python -> python3
```

Comment: I did this but stil not working

Comment: @Soufianeamimi do you get the same error? What happens if you try `which python2 python3 python`?

Comment: /usr/bin/python2
/usr/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python

Comment: neither python or python3 is working

Comment: @Soufianeamimi so you have the binaries, what error messages are you getting?

Comment: `Erreur du serveur!
Le serveur a été victime d'une erreur interne et n'a pas été capable de faire aboutir votre requête.

Message d'erreur:
End of script output before headers: python.py

Si vous pensez qu'il s'agit d'une erreur du serveur, veuillez contacter le webmestre.

Error 500
localhost
Apache/2.4.53 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1o PHP/8.1.6 mod_perl/2.0.12 Perl/v5.34.1`

Comment: @Soufianeamimi you will need to look at your Apache logs (`/var/log/apache2/error.log` probably), but my immediate assumption is going to be that your Python script needs have permissions set for the apache server process to be able to run it.